# Change font of text on links in graph Mermaid

Tags: css, graph, mermaid

I want to change the font (color, size...) of the text on the link (`Change_font`), but I am not able to figure out. Can someone help?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/9.0.1/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
  graph TD;
  A[Hello]--Change_font-->B[of_text]
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can style the text on the line with [linkStyle](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=styling-links), also update the original code from `graph` to [`flowchart`](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=graph).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mermaid/9.0.1/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<div class="mermaid">
flowchart TB
    %% Colors %%
    classDef blue fill:#2374f7,stroke:#000,stroke-width:2px,color:#fff
    classDef green fill:#16b552,stroke:#000,stroke-width:2px,color:#fff

    A[Hello]:::blue ---> |Change_font| B[of_text]:::green

    %% Link Color %%
    linkStyle 0 stroke:blue,stroke-width:2px,color:red;
</div>
```

Comment: How to change the background color of Change_font (which is a link text)? Following line is not working:
linkStyle 0 fill:#2374f7,stroke:blue,stroke-width:2px,color:red;

Comment: @SunilSingh I only manage to do it changing the theme secondaryColor according to this link: https://mermaid.js.org/config/theming.html#customizing-themes-with-themevariables

Answer (score 1):

Styling links

```
linkStyle 0 stroke-width:2px,fill:green,stroke:green;
```

full API documentation link
https://unpkg.com/mermaid@7.0.3/dist/www/flowchart.html#styling-and-classes